# In dropdown nothing is visible.Though on hovering it is.Why?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can add the background color to it but then without selecting also that color will appear. I want to have the same color on showing that dropdown:

[image]

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: Use this css     select, option { color: black; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `background` is white and also the `color` of text is white that the reason you don't see the text
When you hover on text the background change to blue and you see it..
 **Set `color` to `text` and you will see the text...**

```css
option{
color:black;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

**OR `background` to dropdown**

```css
option{
color:white;
}
select{
background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
    <select>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
```